# How to test database actions in asp.net core integration test?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, integration-testing, entity-framework-core

I am trying to integration test my app.

for example, in my `AbController` I have `PostAb(AbDTO abDTO)` method, and I want to test that calling this method will add abDTO to db.

now my test setup:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("testing")
            .UseStartup<Startup>());

        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }
```

and my test should look like:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task PostAbSanity()
    {
        await _client.PostAsync("/rest/v1/Ab", new Ab{Id=1});
        _context.Abs.find(1).should().NotBeNull();
    }
```

but, how can I inject _context into test? in my app I inject it through constructors, but in tests I cant.

thanks!

Comment: I would suggest then that you do a get after the post to verify that posted record was created.

Comment: But not for all my post method exists the contrary get, and vice versa

Comment: and also I'm not sure It's good Idea, since instead the test will focus on it's method, it'll call also many other API for seeding the db etc. is this the normal way integration test should work?

Comment: Your last two comments were not clear. I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: I meant that if I use your suggestion - I'll need for every integration test that test "Get" to use some "Post" to seed the db, and for every test that check "Post" method, to use another "Get" to see that post passed. 
but in some cases my API include just GET, and in other cases just POST, and I dont sure it's good idea to add the missing GET/POST which needed only for tests. 
also, I want to test some API method, but for seeding the db I'll use some other methods, and the test get out of focus, it'll failed on changes that not related to the subject of the test, and can be very long.

Comment: OK I understand what you mean now. point taken.

Comment: You can mock your _context instance inside of your test constructor

Comment: @H.Herzl - mock it? it is an integration test..

Comment: You need to provide more details about your code, can you show your context code please ?

Comment: @H.Herzl nothing special, it's exactly like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db . and the integration test like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing . then I want to access _context in the test himself

Comment: Are you talking about a db context ?

Comment: yes, access BloggingContext in the first link

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using SqlLite, so you can edit your SetUp method like this:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseEnvironment("testing")
        .UseStartup<Startup>());

    _client = _server.CreateClient();

    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();

    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./blog.db");

    _context = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
}
```

Please let me know if this is useful

Comment: no, it's wont replace the _context which registered in startup.cs like: `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
`
see in first link

Comment: What are you using? Sql Server or SqlLite

Comment: in integration test I'm using sql server to be as most same to my real db as possible.

Comment: OK, I think there is a misunderstand about "injection" in unit tests, if you take a look on this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1112848/creating-web-api-in-asp-net-core, in unit tests there is a "mock" for DbContext, why do you want to make this for your case ?

Comment: I'm not on unit test. i'm on writing an integration tests, in my unit test i mocked db (im-memory db) of course

Comment: I get your point, in that case the db context will be injected by web api project when you init the server in your SetUp method

Answer (score 1):

While I will concede that integration testing with an in-memory database is the most thorough and safe way to work, my specific situation would make this aspect extremely difficult and time consuming.  I am using a hosted SQL development server that I overwrite after a period of tests.  I worked for several days and found the below to be the process that gave me the results I was looking for.

- DotNet Core 2.1
- Hexagonal (Onion) architecture needing to test the business logic written in my Data 
  Access Layer

Program.CS file I added:

```
//for integration testing
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

My Integration Test File:

```
using Core.Data.Entities.Model;
using Core.Data.Entities.UTIA;
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Profile.Data.Repos;
using Profile.Domain.DomainObjects;
using Super2.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace Profile.Test
{
    public class EmployeeProfileIntegrationTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public EmployeeProfileIntegrationTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _client = factory.CreateClient();

        }

        private DBContext GetContext()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>()
                .UseSqlServer("Server = 'Connection String from appsettings'")
                .Options;

            var context = new DBContext(options);
            return context;
        }



        [Fact]
        public async Task TestChildProtectionEmployeeGetData()
        {
            //Arrange
            var ApplicationUserId = XXXX;
            var repo = new EmployeeProfileRepo(GetContext());

            //ACT
            var sut = await repo.GetChildProtectionHistory(ApplicationUserId);

            //Assert
            var okResult = sut.Should().BeOfType<List<DomainObject>>().Subject;
            okResult.First().ApplicationUserId.Should().Be(XXXX);
        }
    }
}
```

While I am injecting my context into a different layer, I would suspect that it would work the same for a controller.  I included the startup snippet as this caused me some issues as the testserver was looking for IWebHostBuilder instead of the default Core2.1 IWebHost.

Either way, this worked for me.  Hope you can get some help from this.